# How can I save the items in my shopping cart? Javascript & JQuery only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new here and I have a problem. I want the items from my shopping cart to be saved when I refresh the site (or navigate from another side).

That is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Shopping Cart </h1>
<div id='frm'>
        <label>Movie: </label>
        <input type="text" id="pname" size="20"><br>
        <label>Number of tickets: </label>
        <input id='pqty' type='number'><br>
        <label>price class €</label>
        <select id="priceclass"> 
            <option>5</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>12</option>
        </select> <br>
        <label></label><button onclick="addItem()"> In the shopping cart </button>
        </div>
    <div id='shopping cart'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my script file. I guess I have to code something with load and save but it doesn't work. I tried to enter the save and load - function but something is wrong:

```
 inames = []
 iqtyp = []
 iprice = []

function addItem(){
            inames.push(document.getElementById('pname').value); 
            iqtyp.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('pqty').value));
            iprice.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('priceclass').value));

            displayCart();
        }

function displayCart() {
            shoppingcartdata = '<table><tr><th>Movie</th><th>Number of tickets</th><th>Price class € </th><th>Total €</th></tr>';

            total = 0;

            for (i=0; i<inames.length; i++){
                total += iqtyp[i] * iprice[i]
                shoppingcartdata += "<tr><td>" + inames[i] +"</td><td>" + iqtyp[i] + "</td><td>" + iprice[i] + "</td><td>" + iqtyp[i] * iprice[i] + "</td><td><button onclick='delElement(" + i + ")' >Delete</button></td></tr>"
            }

            shoppingcartdata += '<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>' + total + '</td></tr></table>' 

            document.getElementById('shopping cart').innerHTML = shoppingcartdata;

            saveCart();
}

function saveCart(){
    localStorage.setItem("shoppingcartdata", JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function loadCart(){
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingcartdata"));
}

loadCart;

function delElement(a){
      inames.splice(a,1);
      iqtyp.splice(a,1)
      iprice.splice(a,1)
      displayCart()
}
```

Comment: oh, and I corrected loadCart to  loadCart(); !!

Answer (score 0):

> I want the items from my shopping cart to be saved when I refresh the site

maybe this helps:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  saveCart();
};
```

or written in jquery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  saveCart();
});
```

saveItems() would be called when the visitor is leaving the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use coockie plugin - https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

```
//get coockies
$.cookie('cookie_name');

//set coockies
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'example');
```

Do not use localstorage.